# implement stored procedure in code first existing database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am working on project using ASP.NET, C#, MVC 5 and Entity Framework. I have implemented generic DBContext and Generic repository and using UnitOfWorks for independent business function, which is all working fine. I need to use stored procedure (that is already saved along with database) with define behavior and I am struggling with that

### my stored procedure

```
USE [DORIS_DB_01]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFunctionByID](
@FunctionId INT
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * 
FROM Functions As Fun
WHERE Function_ID = @FunctionId
END
```

my intention is to call stored procedure in UnitOfWork, if this is correct way

### Generic Repository

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class
{

    IQueryable<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id);
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();

}
```

### Repository Implementation

```
 public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbSet<TEntity> _DbSet;
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    public GenericRepository()
    {

    }

    public GenericRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        this._dbContext = dbContext;
        _DbSet = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }


    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _DbSet;
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        var receive_ID = id;

        return _DbSet;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

rest of code can be found here:

[best practice to implement repository pattern and unitOfWork in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707563/best-practice-to-implement-repository-pattern-and-unitofwork-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you well but check http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/677043/Execute-Raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework

this article shows how to execute raw sql query. Now in the repository you can create method 'ExecuteStoredProcedure' to expose it for unit of work.

Comment: i know i can use linq but need to use store procedure